# Dataverse: import MultiSelect Options from Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerapps, dataverse, power-platform

I am trying to import data from Excel into the Dataverse. The Excel data contains MultiSelect options which need to be formatted as a Choice (with multiple selections allowed) in the Dataverse.

I have tried importing using the name or value of the choice, and I have tried searching the internet for various other solutions. I have also tried downloading an Excel template of my Dataverse table and re-uploading the template.

No matter what I try, I keep on getting the same/a similar error: Table Test_Date field test_field is a test_choice Choice data type. The value option 1;option 2;option 1/option 2 is not a valid value for the test_choice choice field.

How can I resolve this and upload MultiSelect options from an Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the **display values** of the multiselect using semicolon `;`.

e.g. Consider the below multiselect options

[image: Multiselect options]

if you want to set two values then add `Small; Medium`.

[image: Adding multiselect option in Excel]